# Javascript : Adding a method to a parent class / to be inherited

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to add a method "bar" to a parent class A, **after** a subclass B are is defined, so that the method is inherited. Is it possible?

I tried the following code

```
function A() {
   this.foo = function () {
       console.log('foo')
   }
}
function B() {
   A.call(this)
}

// (trying to) add a new method to A

A.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log('bar');
}

// It works with instances of A
var a = new A()     
a.foo()            // ok
a.bar()            // ok

// but not with an instance of B
var b = new B()     
b.foo()            // this works
b.bar()            // not this one <------

/*  
   Exception: b.bar is not a function
   @Scratchpad/3:17:1
*/
```

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: well because `a` and `b` aren't instances of the same class..

Comment: you can do `Object.prototype.bar=function() {..}` to add it to *all* objects but that brush may be a lot wider than you want

Answer (score 1):

If you need just fix your code, you can link methods like this:

```
function B() {
   A.call(this)
   for(var i in A.prototype){ this[i] = A.prototype[i]; }
}
```

But i think it is bad way.

Answer (score 1):

```
function A() {
   this.foo = function () {
       console.log('foo');
   };
}
function B() {
   A.call(this);
}

// (trying to) add a new method to A

A.prototype.bar = function () {
    console.log('bar');
};
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
// It works with instances of A
var a = new A()  ;   
a.foo()  ;          // ok
a.bar()  ;          // ok

// but not with an instance of B
var b = new B() ;    
b.foo()   ;         // this works
b.bar()  ;
```

I case of functional-type of inheritance - you can't  add methods, that don't exists in class. Use prototypes

Comment: Or `Object.setPrototypeOf()` , but it's for new browsers :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir here's a qoute - If you care about performance you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create(). - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

Comment: @shabunc Yes. but keep reading : _Object.setPrototypeOf() is in the latest ECMAScript 6 standard draft. It is generally considered the proper way to set the prototype of an object, vs. the more controversial Object.prototype.__proto__ property._  I think the red alert at the beginning talks about `__proto__` thingy. well ....  I'll go with the standard anyway.

Comment: It worls, but having the "fix" the subclasses after extending the parent class has its drawbacks. There can be many subclasses....

Answer (score 1):

```
// if you define the prototype as an object
var A = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log('foo');
    }
};

// and define constructors using Object.create
function newA() {
   return Object.create(A);
};

function newB() {
    return Object.create(newA());   
};

// you can add methods to the prototype
A.bar = function () {
    console.log('bar');
};

// it works with instances of A
var a = newA()     
a.foo();
a.bar();

// and instances of B
var b = newB();  
b.foo();
b.bar();

// you can even modify the prototype after the fact
A.baz = function() {
    console.log('baz');   
};

// and that will work as well
a.baz();
b.baz();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5s8ahvLq/

If you don't want the latter behavior of being able to edit the protoype after the fact, use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or something like underscore or lodash that provides that functionality:

```
function newA() {
    return Object.create(Object.assign({}, A));
}
```

Comment: Seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks a lot to all.

Comment: Can't you override some things in the sub class and use a static method in parent class? Calling bar of A and B of A seperately

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it. Could you please explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing:

```
B.prototype.__proto__ = A.prototype
```

If you don't like using `__proto__` you can use:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

Comment: Setting `__proto__` is discouraged ( i'm not the dv)

Comment: @RoyiNamir true, you can also use `Object.create()`, I guess `__proto__` is old school :p

Comment: Yes :-). I don't think it will ever be 100% obsolete.